# export react hook by changing its signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-modules, javascript-import

I want to change a hook name and its return values while exporting them.
Here is my use case.
I want to use [notistack](https://iamhosseindhv.com/notistack/api) api to show some toasts in my application. However, because I don't like the name `snackbar` I want to change it to `toast`. Here is how I start doing it:

```
export { SnackbarProvider as ToastProvider, useSnackbar as useToast } from 'notistack';
```

But I can't manage to change the name of the variables returned from the `useSnackbar` hook.

```
const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
```

should be

```
const { addToast, closeToast } = useToast();
```

how can I achieve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom hook that wraps the `useSnackbar` hook as follow:

```
import { SnackbarProvider, useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

export const useToast = () => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  return { addToast: enqueueSnackbar, closeToast: closeSnackbar };
};

export const SnackbarProvider = ToastProvider;
```

You can learn more about building custom hooks on the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html